# "show databases" doesn't show databases

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have the following DBs visible in phpmyadmin:

[image]

but when I type the command `show databases;` it doesn't show all of them:

```
sudo mysql -u root

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| phpmyadmin         |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: permissions? wrong server? root could have any permissions, who knows.

Comment: @Drew It's on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `SHOW DATABASES` it only shows you the databases the current user has access to.

Comment: Well I'm the current user of all of these DBs, how can I tell it?

Comment: @Milen The point is that phpmyadmin might be connecting with a different user than `root`, which may not have complete permissions ad would be conventional. The user phpmyadmin is using may have created databases but not supplied `GRANT`s that affect `root`. If you want root to have all permissions, you may need to apply them. `SHOW GRANTS FOR root@localhost` and also find the PMA user from its config file and  `SHOW GRANTS FOR that_pma_user@localhost`.